# How can I use Mersenne Twister in Java?

Tags: java, constructor, instance

I plan to use Mersenne Twister I can get from here: https://cs.gmu.edu/~sean/research/, but I am wondering how to use it. I made two toy examples. Which do you think is better? Are there clear reasons for your choice?

What I want to do is to make high quality pseudo-random numbers and to make sure the repeatability.

Example 1 (each class has its own MersenneTwister instance)

```
class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MersenneTwister mt = new MersenneTwister(1);
        Bar b = new Bar();
    }
}
class Bar {
    MersenneTwister mt;
    Bar() {
        this.mt = new MersenneTwister(2);
    }
}
```

Example 2 (different classes share one MersenneTwister instance)

```
class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MersenneTwister mt = new MersenneTwister(1);
        Bar b = new Bar(mt);
    }
}
class Bar {
    MersenneTwister mt;
    Bar(MersenneTwister mt) {
        this.mt = mt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sharing gives you possible thread-safety issues. Be careful.

Comment: According to the instruction of the webpage, the class, MersenneTwister is thread safe, but I am afraid multithread program where MT class is shared may not be repeatable

Comment: This is because mt.randInt(10) will not be called in the same order every time.

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely that anyone is going to take the time to analyze the contents of that link.

Regardless, without knowing anything else about it, I don't like Example #1 for one simple reason: `mt` in your main method is entirely unused.

```
MersenneTwister mt = new MersenneTwister(1);
```

That line of code is no different from...

```
new MersenneTwister(1);
```

... and that line of code serves no (apparent) purpose other than to waste CPU cycles, space on the heap, and possibly to throw an exception.

Your second example, on the other hand, affords you more flexibility in how `Bar` works. It accomplishes this by letting you specify the state of your new `Bar` instance as opposed to all `Bar`s being initialized with some magical state.

Comment: I think the first example shows that there are two instances of the PNG, and not shared by different classes. The fact that the first instance is never used is not really important to the question. Though it'd be better to show some usage.

Comment: As @LukeLee writes, I simply mean two classes have their own MT instances in the first example. I could write something like mt.nextInt(10), but I did not come up with a good example. Sorry about that.